# Save data from my list collection

Tags: c#, windows, list, collections, save

I am working on `HighScore` Page and Need to save a list of `HighScores`.
Unfortunately I can't find anything concerning Saving a list collection. 
My underlying code is the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<User> HighScores { get; set; }
DateTime Datum = DateTime.Now;

this.HighScores = new ObservableCollection<User>(); 
this.HighScores.Add(new User() { Name = "Michel Platini", HighScore = 10, Datum = "01/05/1990" });
this.HighScores.Add(new User() { Name = "Pele", HighScore = 12, Datum = "09/12/2004" });   
this.HighScores.Add(new User() { Name = "Ronaldo", HighScore = 14, Datum = "05/05/1977" });   
this.HighScores.Add(new User() { Name = "Cacau", HighScore = 15, Datum = "17/04/1989" });  
this.HighScores = new ObservableCollection<User>(this.HighScores.OrderByDescending(x => x.HighScore));

this.DataContext = this;

this.InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = this;


private void SaveScore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
m = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Datum);
i = tbName.Text;
HighScores.Add(new User() { Name = i, HighScore = z, Datum = m });
this.HighScores = new ObservableCollection<User>(this.HighScores.OrderByDescending(x => x.HighScore));
```

I hope anyone wants to help me as I am desperately looking for days (without any Progress),

Comment: Where do you want to save it to?

Comment: Here's a simple example of how to serialize and deserialize from XML. http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization